# Windows Defender - How can I temporarily disable calls to MpCmdRun -GetDeviceTicket using registry editor

Tags: windows, windows-defender, regedit

I have noticed that calls to MgCmdRun.exe GetDeviceTicket -AccessKey <SOME_KEY> were causing glitches in a rendering application I am working on.

I was wondering if there was a way I could temporarily disable these calls.

Here is a list of what I have tried:

- Disabling WAM (Windows Automatic Maintenance) using the registry: https://winaero.com/how-to-disable-automatic-maintenance-in-windows-10/
- Disabling Windows Defender RealTimeMonitoring using the registry and powershell: https://www.majorgeeks.com/content/page/how_to_turn_on_or_off_windows_defender_real_time_protection.html

As of right now, none of these solutions worked. By disabling WAM, I noticed that Windows Defender Scheduled tasks were no longer being executed. However, some calls to GetDeviceTicket were still being made.

I would appreciate a solution that would disable/enable these calls without the need to reboot the system. I also still need Windows Defender to be running.

EDIT:

I noticed that if I go under Windows Security > Protection Updates and click on `Check for updates`, the `GetDeviceTicket` is called

Thanks!

Comment: Can you whitelist the App that makes the call?  That would be the best way.

Comment: I don't know how I can get the name of the app that makes the call. I am using `mpcmdrun.exe -GetFiles` to get the logs and then I browse the file called `MpCmdRun-NetworkService.log` in order to get the log of the call to `mpcmdrun GetDeviceTicket -AccessKey ...`

Comment: I also know that if I go under Windows Security > Protection Updates and click on `Check for updates`, the GetDeviceTicket is called